# ms access - set position of cursor in textfield to start only if textbox is empty

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I would like to do is in my formatted (inputmask) textbox set the cursor position to the first position if there is nothing in the textbox. BUT if there is something set the position to where ever the user clicked.

Right now I have:

```
If (txtCR.Value = "" Or IsNull(txtCR.Value)) Then
    Me.txtCR.SelStart = 0
End If
```

But even if there is something in the textbox the cursor is moved to the first position.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: once you figure out where the user clicked, then you just `SelStart = position_that_was_clicked`.

Comment: do you know how to find out where the user clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you?  (MsgBox line to see if you are getting the right value.  You can take it out for production, obviously.)

```
If (txtCR.Value = "" Or IsNull(txtCR.Value)) Then
    Me.txtCR.SelStart = 0
Else
    Me.txtCR.SelStart = Me.txtCR.SelStart + Me.txtCR.SelLength
End If

MsgBox Me.txtCR.SelStart
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Good luck! =)